# how to remove .php file extension on static files htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I'm trying to remove the file extension from the url of the static pages
`sitename.com/page.php` → `sitename.com/page`

I made it so that my wp url looks like this (if it matters)
`sitename.com/wp/` → `sitename.com/`

FTP looks like this:

```
- root directory
  - static php files
  - htaccess file
  - wp folder
```

Adding this to `.htaccess` doesn't do anything

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Current `.htaccess` contents:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /500.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L] 

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

How do I achieve this by only adding a code in the `.htaccess` file?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your code looks ok and it should work if you type `/file` instead of `/file.php` in the browser.

Comment: @AmitVerma it just directs me to the 404 page not found :( but when I check /file.php the page would load

Comment: Why not set the DocRoot of your webserver to that `wp` folder? Otherwise, why not move the WordPress folder to the root directory?

Answer (score 0):

I realized the files are getting overwritten so the only way I can go about it is to create individual folders for each static file (i.e., page/index.php)
so that I can achieve this `sitename.com/page.php` → `sitename.com/page`

Answer (score -1):

The steps to remove file extensions are:

1. Login to your cPanel account.
2. Go to **File Manager** – in the **FILES** Section
3. In the File Manager go to the **Settings** button on the top right corner.
4. On the Preferences window that will appear, check the **Show Hidden Files (dotfiles)** option. Click the **Save** button to apply the settings.
5. Now navigate to the .htaccess file. If the file doesn’t exist you will need to create it.
6. Click the **Edit** button from the File Manager top menu.
7. Add the below lines to the .htaccess file. Click the **Save Changes** button and then the **Close** button.

#remove php file extension-e.g. https://example.com/file.php will become https://example.com/file

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

8. Now the Apache web server will remove .php extension from URLs.

To remove .html extension use:

```
#remove html file extension-e.g. https://example.com/file.html will become https://example.com/file
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

> You can also edit .htaccess files on your web hosting account via an
> FTP client like FileZilla.

Comment: Please share more details. Are you sure this helps to move `sitename.com/wp/`  to `sitename.com`?

Comment: @NicoHaase check the question first. Here the question is to remove the .php file extension & you talk about redirection

Comment: "I made it so that my wp url looks like this (if it matters) sitename.com/wp/ → sitename.com/" - how does your answer relate to this requirement?

Comment: Both are different thing create question related this